# Is it possible to combine the Sobolev inequality in two regions into one in the whole region?

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Assume that $M$ is a non-compact manifold and $K$ is a compact set of $M$. Assume that Sobolev inequality holds on $M\backslash K$:
$$
(\int f^{\frac{2m}{m-2}}~~ d\mu)^\frac{m-2}{m}\le C \int |\nabla f|^2 d\mu, \quad   f\in C^\infty_0(M\backslash K)
$$
Also on K, Sobolev inequality holds:
$$
(\int f^{\frac{2m}{m-2}}~~ d\mu)^\frac{m-2}{m}\le C \int |\nabla f|^2 d\mu, \quad   f\in C^\infty_0(K)
$$
Is it possible to get Sobolev inequality on whole $M$?